# How to insert data to sqlite through user input?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am a beginner in mobile application building. I have tried to put insert data function in my android studio but it seems that those insert function doesn't work and the input data can't be inserted. Please help.

I put some code in MainActivity.java and DatabaseHelper.java. It doesn't give me any error report but when I have tried to run the emulator and input data, my input can be inserted to sqlite database.

//oncreateMainActivity

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        name2 = findViewById(R.id.name2);
        birthdate2 = findViewById(R.id.birthdate2);
        area2 = findViewById(R.id.area2);
        receiver2 = findViewById(R.id.receiver2);

        submit2 = findViewById(R.id.submit2);
        submit2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                name = name2.getText().toString();
                birth = birthdate2.getText().toString();
                area = area2.getText().toString();
                receiver = receiver2.getText().toString();
...
        insertData2 (name, birth, area, receiver);
...

public void insertData2 (String name,String birth,String area, String receiver){
        boolean add_data = myDb.insertData(name,birth,area,receiver);

        if (!add_data){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Something went wrong><", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success to add data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

//DatabaseHelper.java

```
public boolean insertData(String childname ,String bornday, String areaprogram, String receiverid){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1, childname);
        contentValues.put(COL2, bornday);
        contentValues.put(COL3, areaprogram);
        contentValues.put(COL4, receiverid);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: show us your `insertData` function

Comment: @JohnJoe Oh, the code for insertData function is in DatabaseHelper.java above. Please help. thank you..

Comment: what issue are you facing now? Data get inserted using emulator, but not in real device ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Yes, I still use emulator, not yet in real device. but when I tried to put database file, only the database and tables have created but not the data that I have input.

Comment: In insertData2 function, did it displayed Success to add data! ?

Comment: @JohnJoe No, It fail to insert data.

Comment: check my answer, use try and catch to see what is happening.

Comment: @JohnJoe I have tried your advice, and gladly I get some error message, thank you for helping me find the error. I put the error message below your answer, and I'll check the error to see what should I do. I'll update it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st parameter of the method `put()` is the name of the column, but you pass the value.
Change to this (of course replace with your column names like `"Name"`, `"Birthdate"`, etc):

```
public boolean insertData(String Name,String Birthdate,String Area, String ID){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ColunNameForName, Name);
    contentValues.put(ColunNameForBirthdate, Birthdate);
    contentValues.put(ColunNameForArea, Area);
    contentValues.put(ColunNameForID, ID);

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because i put the name of the column same with it string name. Is that cause this insert data problem? @forpas

Comment: All these parameters: `String Name,String Birthdate,String Area, String ID` contain the values that you want to insert, like `Bob, 2019-04-07, somewhere, 10`. They are not column names.

Comment: Oh, i see. I get your explanation and I have edited the first paramater in put(), but still face the same problem.>< (I have revised my code in DatabaseHelper.java above).

Comment: What is the problem? Post the class SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: thank you, it has been solved!! I change the code based on your advice also create new emulator to create new db and it works! I can insert my input data to sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't give me any error report

You should use try and catch block to see what is happening.

```
try{
   boolean add_data = myDb.insertData(name,birth,area,receiver);
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Success to add data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: 2019-04-08 11:28:30.444 18153-18153/com.example.inputgetdata E/SQLiteLog: (1) table sponsorship_table has no column named child_name
2019-04-08 11:28:30.448 18153-18153/com.example.inputgetdata E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting birthdate=29011989 child_name=erik receiver_id=1 area_program=nias
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table sponsorship_table has no column named child_name (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO sponsorship_table(birthdate,child_name,receiver_id,area_program) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: are you sure you have `child_name` ?

Comment: Thank you John, your answer is helping me so much to know what error is in my code!!

Comment: Yes, I have the child_name column. The problem is when I use the same emulator and try to revise my database then that same emulator will run the old code. I need to create new emulator when I revised my code.

Comment: I think you just need to re-install your app instead of create a new emulator. Every time you create/modify a table or column, you need to re-install again. Is because of the version issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your DatabaseHelper class have an SQLiteDatabase object that executes the SQL command.

```
    SQLiteDatabase database
    String myTable = ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable (yourColumns);");
    database.execSQL(myTable);
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO myTable(yourData);"
```

Comment: Yes, I have. The database and column can be created but i get inserting data problem. The insert function is in DatabaseHelper.java box above. What do you think about it? thank you... @PvCruz